# Using Windows AMI rather then Linux on Amazon Cloud to deploy PHP Application

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, xampp, ec2-ami

Currently i have deployed my application on Linux AMI instance on Amazon cloud.
But i am facing lot of problems there like some php files dont work on Linux beacause Linux is case sensitive, imagecreatefromstring function also don't works on Linux because GD package is not installed there by default in PHP. Moreover i can't succeded in installing phpmyadmin there.
Everytime i have to perform database operations by command prompt there using Putty.
Moreover my scripts responsible to send frequent emails to various users also don't work on Linux
while working fine on Windows.

Overall I am using XAMPP on windows  and everything works fine here.
But in case og Linux server i need to manually install PHP packages,mysql packages,PHP graphic packages,PHP mailing PEAR packages. etc.

Please tell me if i run my application on Windows Server 2008 AMI there then will i face any security or performacne related issues there?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security and performance depends on a lot of factors. You're basically asking "is Linux better than Windows" as a catch-all question.

For what it's worth, I run several Windows EC2 images, and have absolutely no security or performance concerns with the underlying platform.